# Blood relation - How A is related to B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is a data sufficiency question -

**Q -** How is A related to B?

```
Statement I. B is the only son of D who is the daughter of A's father.

Statement II. B is the father of C and is the only son of A's mother.
```

**A -**

**I.** If statement I alone is sufficient to answer the question.

**II** If statement II alone is sufficient to answer the question.

**III** If the data either in statement I or statement II alone is sufficient to answer the question.

**IV** If both the statement together is not sufficient to answer the question.

**V** If both the statement together is necessary to answer the question.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I think the answer will be **Option I**.

From statement I, I got A is the uncle of B

From statement II, I got A is the sister or the brother of B

But I am not sure if I am right.

Please help me solve this question.

Comment: Eh, from my understanding statement $I$ says $B$ is the son of $D$ and then statement $II$ says $B$ is also a sibling of $D$, so that $B$ and $D$ are siblings and mother-son. Are you sure this is worded correctly? Maybe I'm completely offbase and am reading this wrong...

Comment: Why does statement I tell you that A is male?  You have assumed it when using the word "uncle".

Comment: Interesting , re data sufficiency, the user name ' Man From India' narrows things down to around 600,000,000 possibilities.

Comment: Have you reduced each statement into a series of short, simple sentences?  I see five such sentences in Statement I.  Doing so makes it easier to see what has been said in pieces that are individually understandable.

Comment: Leaving out punctuation changes the meaning of of these sentences! None of the sons of A is the daughter of anybody, so "B is the only son of D who is the daughter of A's father" cannot be true. Putting a comma after D makes a sensible alternative reading possible, but I would frankly say "...son of D, and D is..." to make things clear.

Comment: @Fabien: Why can't A be male (and so A = B)? And how does that fit with the first statement?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, yes you're right, my brain implicitely said : $A\neq B$ but it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Statement I:  D has a unique male child.  D's male child is named B.  D is a daughter, so D is female.  D is the child of an unnamed male called A's father.  A is a child of an unnamed male called A's father.

(using ":" for children and "()" for collecting sibling subtrees...)

A's father - male: (A - unknown sex, D - female : B - male)

Statement II: B is a father, so is male.  B has a child named C.  B is a child of an unnamed female called A's mother.  A is a child of an unnamed female called A's mother.

A's mother - female: (A - unknown sex, B - male: C - unknown sex)

A is an aunt or an uncle of B, but neither statement is sufficient to resolve which is the case.  A is also a sibling of B, but neither statement is sufficient to resolve the sex of A and therefore whether A is a brother or a sister to B.

Interestingly, B's mother is D (statement I), D's father is A's father (statement I) and B's father is A's father (statement II).  Therefore B's mother is also his half-sister.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  This is true.  (Although once I realized my (second, actually) translation was going to be insufficient, I became a little lazy...)

Comment: Actually, because B's mother is D, it means that A's mother is also D. Definitely something wrong with the problem statement, hopefully!